# Is that possible to run docker containers with devices as volumes?

Tags: linux, docker, containers, volumes

Now we can run docker containers like `docker run --device /dev/fuse $IMAGE`.

But Kubernetes couldn't support host deivces yet, refer to https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/5607 .

Is that possible to mount devices like volumes? We have try `-v /dev/fuse:/dev/fuse` but the container didn't have permissions to open that char device. Can we add more `capabilities` to do that?

We have tried `docker run --cap-add=ALL -v /dev/fuse:/dev/fuse` and it didn't work. I think `--device` or `--privileged` is needed for this scenario.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the device? That determines which capabilities you need.

Comment: Thanks @KarlSt and we want to mount the fuse device. We have tried `--cap-add=ALL` and it did not work to mount.